# In-memory stream for Ruby

Tags: ruby, stream, protocol-buffers, in-memory

When working with Protocol Buffers the real message size becomes known when a whole object is written to `IO`. So I use following approach: write object to intermediate stream, get it's size and then write whole data, with header containing size int, to TCP socket.

What I do not like in following code is the `message_size` function which uses real disk file instead of memory stream.

```
require 'protocol_buffers'

module MyServer
  class AuthRequest < ProtocolBuffers::Message
    required :int32, :vers, 1
    required :int32, :orgID, 2
    required :string, :password, 3
  end

  class MyServer
    def self.authenticate(socket, params)
      auth = AuthRequest.new(:vers => params[:vers], :orgID => params[:orgID], :password => params[:password])
      size = message_size(auth)
      if size.present?
        socket.write([size, 0].pack 'NN')
        auth.serialize(socket)
        socket.flush
      end
    end

    def self.message_size(obj)
      size = nil
      io = File.new('tempfile', 'w')
      begin
        obj.serialize(io)
        io.flush
        size = io.stat.size + 4
      ensure
        io.close
      end
      size
    end
  end
end
```

Controller:

```
require 'my_server'
require 'socket'

class MyServerTestController < ActionController::Base
  def test
    socket = TCPSocket.new('192.168.1.15', '12345')
    begin
      MyServer::MyServer.authenticate(socket, {vers: 1, orgID: 100, password: 'hello'})
    ensure
      socket.close
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: try http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html

Comment: You're safer to use real disk instead of memory. Buffering into memory is not scalable, and, with the speed of disks being what they are, compared to the speed of the internet, using disk I/O is not going to be a bottleneck, it's your internet connection. I'd be using Ruby's [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) class for this.

Comment: @Uri Agassi: I need not a string stream, but a binary stream.

Comment: @the Tin Man: What are you saying... For over 15 years I've been using memory streams in web applications, in Delphi, in .NET and everything was fine, but now, in Ruby, it turns out to be a big no-no. What a surprise...

Comment: It's not a big no-no with Ruby, it's something to be careful with in any language/environment. If you are dealing with files bigger than your available buffer size you're going to have problems. There is no way, from your description to tell what hardware resources you have, so, because SO fields requests from people using dinky shared servers, all the way to production sites with dedicated hardware, I shared what's safest. 15 years doesn't matter, it's environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use [`StringIO`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) as your memory stream. Mind you, it is called `StringIO` since it is implemented *on* a string, and it is definitely *not* bound for it being string data - it works just as easily on binary data:

```
def self.message_size_mem(obj)
  size = nil
  io = StringIO.new
  begin
    obj.serialize(io)
    io.flush
    size = io.size + 4
  ensure
    io.close
  end
  size
end


auth = AuthRequest.new(:vers => 122324, orgID: 9900235, password: 'this is a test for serialization')
MyServer.message_size(auth)
# => 47
MyServer.message_size_mem(auth)
# => 47

io = StringIO.new
auth.serialize(io)
io.flush
io.string
# => "\bԻ\a\u0010ˡ\xDC\u0004\u001A this is a test for serialization"
```